# Pending Requests When Posting Data to ASP.NET web API Controller from ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api2

Im working on a SOA project using, ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WEB API. Both projects are inside different solutions, so we have a mvc site and a web api site and the mvc site calls the web api site using http methods operations.

With that cenario in mind, im facing a strange behaviour when POSTING some data to the web API from my mvc controller. When I do GET operations everything works fine. Here's what Im doing:

Inside my cshtml view, i have a js code that do an ajax call to my MVC controller:

**> JS Code inside Create.cshtml:**

```
var create = (function () {
var _init = function (container, starter, url) {
    $(starter).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = this.value.replace(" ", "").split(',');

            terms.pop();

            terms.push(ui.item.label);

            terms.push("");

            this.value = terms.join(",");
            return false;
        },
        search: function (event, ui) {
            if (_extractLast(this.value).length < 3)
                return false;

            return true;
        },
        source: function (request, response) {
            _execute(request, response, url);
        }
    });
};
var _extractLast = function (term) {
    var termArray = term.split(',');
    var lastTerm = termArray[termArray.length - 1];
    return lastTerm.replace(' ', '');
};
var _execute = function (request, response, url) {
    var responseCallback = response;
    $.ajax({
        url: '\Comunication\Contacts',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { termo: _extractLast(request.term) },
        success: function (data) {
            responseCallback($.map(data, function (item) {
                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Id }
            }));
        }
    });
}
return { init: _init };})();
```

And from inside my controller I call a method from a specialized Service layer to do a POST request to my WEB API SITE doing the SOA thing, as you can see bellow:

**> The MVC CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
public class ComunicationController : BaseController{
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<JsonResult> Contacts(string termo)
     {
         var contacts = new ContactServices.ConsumeAsync(new ContactParameter{Term: termo});
         return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
 }
```

**> The Layer SERVICE CODE:**

```
public class ContactServices{
public async Task<List<ContactsDTO>> ConsumeAsync(ContactParameter parameter)
{
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:123456/api/comunication/contacts");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:123456/api/comunication/contacts"), parameter);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ResponseProxy<List<ContactsDTO>>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result.data;
    }
}
```

}

My WEB API SITE accept the request, process the request like expected, no concerns here. But when I return the HttpResponseMessage from my WEB API CONTROLLER to the MVC Site under a POST operation, the request response hangs on forever pending status according to my network monitor....

So basically my request is hanging, the Protocol status is Pending and I never get the request response, heres is a pic:
[Pending Status from My Post Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfIt1.png)
As I said, when I do GET requests to my web api, everything works fine but when I do POST requests this happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ResponseProxy<List<ContactsDTO>>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result.data;
```

The use of the `Result` property of your Task generates a deadlock on you MVC controller. If an API is asynchronous, then always `await` the task.

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var deserialized = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ResponseProxy<List<ContactsDTO>>>(content);
return deserialized.data;
```

To learn more about why you should never block on async methods check this great post:
[Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, you just made my day. I didnt noticed that detail. It really worked, thank you!